# kotlin android remover un item error

Tags: android, kotlin

**error siempre al usar la funcion remove() para quitar un item a lista de personages..**

MAIN>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()  {
    lateinit var mRecyclerView : RecyclerView
    val mAdapter : ADAPTERCLASS = ADAPTERCLASS()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setUpRecyclerView()
        registerForContextMenu(mRecyclerView)
    }

    fun setUpRecyclerView(){
        var gg=  mAdapter.getpersonaggi()
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listakaisauki) as RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        mAdapter.RECYCLERADAPTER(gg, this)
        mRecyclerView.adapter = mAdapter
    }
    override fun onCreateContextMenu(
        menu: ContextMenu?,
        v: View?,
        menuInfo: ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo?
    ) {
         val menuInflater=menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menup,menu)

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo)
    }
    override fun onContextItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId){
            R.id.remove ->{
                makeErrorToast(this,"rimosso ${item.itemId} ",2).show()
                mAdapter.remove(item.itemId)


            }
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item)
    }



}
```

//ADAPTER>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

```
class ADAPTERCLASS  :RecyclerView.Adapter<ADAPTERCLASS.ViewHolder>() {
     var personaggi: MutableList<Modello>  = ArrayList()
    lateinit var context: Context
    fun  RECYCLERADAPTER(personaggi: MutableList<Modello>, context: Context)  {
        this.personaggi = personaggi
        this.context = context
    }
     fun getpersonaggi():MutableList<Modello>{
         var persoanggi:MutableList<Modello> = ArrayList()
         persoanggi.add(Modello("SASORI "       , "sands"         , "https://static.zerochan.net/Sasori.full.1496734.jpg"))
         persoanggi.add(Modello("kisame"        , "water village" , "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/d2/47/a6/d247a62289b22afa68e8152bcc7d15ab.jpg"))
         persoanggi.add(Modello("IATCHI uchiha" , "konoha"        , "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/6f/46/75/6f4675199bf7802b9a9f531a15dbce2b.jpg"))
         persoanggi.add(Modello("pain"          , "RAIN village"  , "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/44/73/b6/4473b64e729795566f1bcf500b6cb677.jpg"))
         persoanggi.add(Modello("obito uchiha"  , "konoha"        , "https://static.zerochan.net/Tobi.full.1217207.jpg"))
         return persoanggi
     }
     fun remove(position: Int){
         getpersonaggi().removeAt(position)
         notifyDataSetChanged()
     }
    //classe viewhold
    class ViewHolder(view:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)  {

        //casting +istanze dei items
        val personaggionome=view.findViewById(R.id.tvpersonaggio)as TextView
        val nomevillagio = view.findViewById(R.id.persoanggiovillaggio) as TextView
        val stagione = view.findViewById(R.id.stagione) as TextView
        val avatar = view.findViewById(R.id.ivAvatar) as ImageView

        fun bin(setpersoanggi:Modello,context: Context){
            personaggionome.text = setpersoanggi.nome
            nomevillagio.text = setpersoanggi.villagio
            avatar.loadUrl(setpersoanggi.prifilo)
             var click=itemView
            click.setOnLongClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(context, setpersoanggi.nome, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                click.showContextMenu()
            }
        }
        fun ImageView.loadUrl(url:String){
            Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(this)
        }
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
         val item=personaggi.get(position)
        holder.bin(item,context)
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return ViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.itemlist,parent,false))
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return personaggi.size
    }
 }
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el error mostrado en el LogCat?, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Process: com.example.akaisukirecyclerview, PID: 4772
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2131165321, Size: 5
        at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:503)
        at com.example.akaisukirecyclerview.MainActivity.remover(MainActivity.kt:68)
        at com.example.akaisukirecyclerview.MainActivity.onContextItemSelected(MainActivity.kt:59)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3563) amigo dime si copie bien :)

Comment: En el código no se muestra el método remover(), cual es la linea 68? @AngioFerretti

Comment: @Jorgesys numero 55, en el main es donde la llamo numero 28 en el adapter esta la funcion  este es el git https://github.com/angiof/recyclerviewuchiha/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/akaisukirecyclerview/MainActivity.kt

Comment: @jorgesy adapter numero 28, en el main lo llamo en la 55

Comment: @AngioFerretti el error que copiaste no coincide con el codigo